# Angular Pass HttpClient from app.module to another module to a service

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing an Angular (ngx-*) NPM Package. I have it compiled properly, and am using it in a new fresh project using `npm link`

The service has the following constructor to inject HttpClient and settings.

Updated.

**MyService**

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('configs') configs: ImyConfigs) {
```

**MyService.Module**

I have the following for root in the module

```
    @NgModule({

      declarations: [
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
 // note that I am not importing HttpClientModule
 // My understanding is that if I do I will get duplicate issues?
      ],
      exports: [],
      providers: []
    })
    export class MyModule {
          static forRoot(configs?: ImyConfigs): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
              ngModule: MyModule,
              providers: [MyService, { provide: 'configs', useValue: configs }]
            };
          }
```

**App.module**

Now in my main project (fresh Angular project using this module) I want to use this service.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MyModule.forRoot(MYCONFIG_CONST)    

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MyService -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyService -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

What am I doing wrong with regards to injecting the HttpClient into myService?

**Edit: I will answer below.**

Comment: you don't need ```HttpModule``` in your imports.

Comment: That was the result of me trying to figure out what is wrong. I added it with clueless hopes it may do something positive.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng serve  --preserve-symlinks
```

Solved the problem.

This is an old project and it was already added to package.json, I just forgot about it ― for ... to long.